# Disable a JButton from a listener that's in a separate class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm writing a pretty big class and don't want to post it here. The question is the following, how do I refer to the button that was pressed in the constructor of a different class? Let's say, I want to disable it after some actions in the listener. If the listener were anonymus or were an inner class of the SomeClass, I would just use the name of the variable like this:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

But how can I do it when my listener is a separate class? Tried using e.getModifiers().setEnabled(false) and e.getSource().setEnabled(false), didn't work.

```
public class SomeClass extends JPanel {
    private JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    public SomeClass() {
        button.setActionCommand("button");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String src = e.getActionCommand();
        if (src.equals("button")) {
            //some actions here
            //then            
        }        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false)`

It must work)

`e.getSource()` return component to which this event refers( [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29))

Comment: Yes, it did work, thank you very much. Nevertheless, it seems to me that this solution is some kind of "cheat". I wonder if there is an "official" way of doing this?

Comment: It's not a cheat it's official method